# Get user object from simple API call without a viewset in Django 3.0.3 using rest_framework_jwt

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to retrieve the user object in order to check if the user is allowed to access a file or not in a web app based on Django and rest_framework_jwt for the REST WebServices.

I have the following settings for my web app:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS':'swiftapp.custom_pagination.CustomPagination',
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

My defined routing:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)
#router.register(r'operation/<str:branch>/<str:filename>/', SwiftFileViewSet, basename='get_queryset') # This didn't work and I don't need a Viewset anyways
router.register(r'operations/(?P<start_date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/(?P<end_date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})$', OperationViewSet, basename='get_queryset')

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'api/', include(router.urls)),
    path('api/operation/<str:branch>/<str:filename>/', get_operation, name='get_operation'),
]
```

In the ModelViewset below (GET method), I'm able to get the authentified user object:

```
class OperationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    authentication_classes = (authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication,)
    queryset = Operation.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.OperationSerializer
    permission_classes = (ReadOnly,)
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user # I can get the user object here
        logger.warning("logged user", user)
        req = self.request.data
        queryset = Operation.objects.filter(branch=user.get_branch(), date__gte=self.kwargs.get('start_date'),date__lte=self.kwargs.get('end_date'))
        return list(queryset)
```

but not in this simple GET API controller:

```
def get_operation(request, section, filename):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    
    user = self.request.user  # I cannot get the user object here
    logger.warning("logged user", user)
    with open("C:\\operations\\" + section + "\\" + filename + ".op", "r") as f:
        file_content = f.read()
        f.close()
    enc = base64.b64encode(bytes(file_content, 'utf-8'))
    
    return HttpResponse(enc)
```

User custom class:

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, first_name, last_name, username, branch, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        if not branch:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a branch')

        user = self.model(
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            username=username,
            branch=branch,
        )

        user.is_superuser = False
        user.is_active = True
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, first_name, last_name, username, branch, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            first_name,
            last_name,
            username,
            password=password,
            branch=branch,
        )
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_active = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False, unique=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False, unique=False)
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True, null=True)

    # is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=False, null=False)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'branch']

    class Meta:
        db_table='auth_user'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin

    def get_branch(self):
        return self.branch
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view ***`get_operation(...)`*** is not *compatible with DRF*. You have to make it compatible with DRF by using the [**`@api_view(...)`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view) decorator. Then you can add the class parameters into the decorator

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, authentication_classes, permission_classes
from rest_framework.response import Response


@api_view(http_method_names=["GET"], )
@authentication_classes((authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication,))
@permission_classes((permissions.IsAuthenticated,))
def get_operation(request, section, filename):
    user = request.user
    return Response({"user pk": user.pk})
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It saved me! :D

Answer (score 1):

Django has library called [PYJWT](https://pypi.org/project/PyJWT/)

first install a library whith

```
pip3 install PyJWT
```

you can define a function that check JWT with your secret and call that function before any response in your views functions.
for example :

```
import jwt


def jwt_authentication(token):
    check = False
    try:
        request_jwt = jwt.decode(token, 'yoursecret', algorithms=['HS512'])
        check = True
    except:
        check = False
    return check
```

and in views.py :

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def obj_add(request):
    if not 'Authorization' in request.headers:
        return Response({'Authorization': 'token is required'}, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
    token = request.headers['Authorization']
    authentication = jwt_authentication(token)
    if not authentication:
        return Response({'Authorization': 'token is not valid'}, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```